# Есть ли способ отличить браузер пользователя и гуглбот средствами js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Вижу, что поисковые роботы, в частности гуглбот с успехом выполняют javascript, а также jquery и т.д. Это видно в панели вебмастера "Просмотреть как Googlebot" в GWT. Скажите а есть ли способ спрятать элемент страницы средствами javascript jquery, просто не хочу чтобы некоторые элементы сайта индексировались гуглботом. Может есть для этого какие-либо другие способы, не посредством js?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677419/how-to-detect-search-engine-bots-with-php

Comment: Можно проверять User-Agent и выводить содержимое в зависимости от него. Также, могут помочь [`<noindex>` и `nofollow`](https://seo-akademiya.com/baza-znanij/osnovyi-seo/noindex-i-nofollow/).

Comment: @Андрей noindex только для яндекса

Comment: @Андрей, проверять useragent - вроде так себе идея - где-то говорилось, что гугл проверяет на такое и оно отрицательно сказывается на рейтинге.

Comment: гугл имеет в своем распоряжении ботов которые вообще ботами не представляются. Это сделано для отслеживания клоаки и других подобных методов. Так что useragent не подходит.

Comment: Описание того, что вы хотите скрыть, сильно помогло бы в поиске ответа на ваш вопрос.